# Injectivity and Surjectivity of adjoint map

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $V$ be the adjoint representation space of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, over $\Bbb C$. Write the basis elements $\{e,f,h\}$ of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$

Let $V_i=\{x\in V: [h,x]= ix\}$, then write:
$$V=\bigoplus_{i\in \Bbb Z} V_i.$$

Why is it true that: $\text{ad} e:V_i\to V_{i+2}$ is injective for $i\leq -1$ and surjective for $i\geq -1$?

It is clear to me that $\text{ad} e$ does map between these spaces. As long as we are not looking at an element that is highest weight in every simple component, then $\text{ad} e$ will have trivial kernel. But if we are in $V_{-1}$ or lower, these are never highest weight elements, so this map must have trivial kernel. Is that true?

Comment: I would like to help you, but in order to do so I will have to undestand your question first. And I am confused, because $\mathfrak g$ is, it seems, an arbitrary $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ representation (did you forget to add that it is finite-dimensional?) and, on the other hand, yout start mentioning the adjoint representation. So, are we dealing with an arbitrary representation or with the adjoint representation? Besides, using $\mathfrak g$ for a representaion is a bad choice. In the context of Lie algebras, these charateres are reserved for Lie algebras, not their modules.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry about that. I have fixed the notation. I was trying to understand the good $\Bbb Z$-grading, that was why I chose $\mathfrak{g}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true, because it is true for every finite-dimensional irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ representation and because every finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ representation is a direct sum of irreducible ones.